# Are there any plugins for LaTeX or TeX in Netbeans, Eclipse or any IDE?

Tags: math-mode, mathjax

I was wondering if there are any plugins for LaTeX or TeX in Netbeans, Eclipse or any IDE? Thank you so much.

Comment: perhaps i'm missing the point, but i'm not sure exactly how math-mode or mathjax is related to the way the question is stated.  do you mean that you want simply to render strings of math in a context other than a complete (la)tex document?

Comment: I was wondering if I can use LaTeX or TeX in an IDE?

Comment: Please see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/8528) (or the comparable [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TeX_editors)).

Comment: (la)tex can certainly be launched from an editor, but others are much better able to answer regarding the usage you ask about.  (sorry.)

Comment: @Jon, THANK YOU!!! FOUND IT. ECLIPSE HAS A PLUGIN. YOU'RE AWESOME =)

Comment: @gordonsung -- Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse has LaTeX plugins (e.g. TeXlipse) + PDF Plugin. I prefer to use KDE (Kile) in Linux and TexStudio in Windows environment. Here is a complete comparison for editor selection on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TeX_editors